# While testing my app that uses shared preferences in some mobile phones it doesn't supports multiple shared preferences? What is the reason for this?

Tags: java, android, xml, sharedpreferences, storage

The problem is that my application that uses multiple shared preferences that fails to resolve data from shared preferences on certain devices. On the installation it works correctly and it has a problem when re launching the application on certain devices.I want to know what is the reason for it?

```
SharedPreferences SchoolDetails = getSharedPreferences("schooldetails", MODE_PRIVATE);
                String orgid = SchoolDetails.getString("Orgid", "");
                SharedPreferences userDetails = getSharedPreferences("userdetails", MODE_PRIVATE);
                String Uname = userDetails.getString("Username", "");
                String pswrd = userDetails.getString("pass", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

Standard preferences do not support error handling. Try another implementation https://github.com/yandextaxitech/binaryprefs

Comment: have you understand my problem? @Анатолий Спитченко

Comment: the code works in most of the devices but in some devices it fails to execute.

Comment: Check package contents /data/data/package_name/shared_prefs/

Comment: As I'm new to Android I don't understand the path you mentioned. Can you give me an example full path .

Comment: The package is on the device. package_name is your applicationId from the build.gradle application level. This package contains all the preference files.

example /data/data/com.google.android.videos/shared_prefs/youtube.xml

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<map>
    <boolean name="check_accounts_sync_status" value="false" />
    <string name="user_account"></string>
    <boolean name="legacy_downloads_have_app_level_drm" value="false" />
    <boolean name="check_accounts_periodic_sync" value="false" />
</map>